# build developer guide for iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, documentation

Is there any standard way to build developer, just making the developers understand the code easily after delivering, if you have sample it's better

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to make your code better, you need to read about SOLID and other object-oriented design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

There are no official Apple developer programming style guides.
I.e.: no official "Programming Standards" exist.

Standard only exist in terms of UI, external appearance of your application.

Normal software development criteria apply:

- commenting
- using software patterns appropriately, as pointed out in another answer, SOLID makes a lot of sense. Just in order to understand Apple Frameworks you need to know software patterns: delegation, visitor, proxy, etc.
- document requisites and change requests, api and architecture if the app is complex
- don't rely too much on bug tracking, these tend to be abused (change requests marked as bugs) and might add too much complexity of their own (JIIRA).
- your organization may adopt an existing programming "quality standard" and adapt it to iOS development. ITIL is and ISO are usually overkill.
- Sometimes it makes no sense to over-optimize and over-engineer everything, including your code and programming standards.